# many to many relation in yii returns empty array

Tags: yii, many-to-many

Though my tables are not empty,it returns me empty array.

```
 class CryptoCurrency extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function relations()
     {
         return array(
             'currencies' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'MiningPool', 'mining_pool_currencies(currency_id,mining_pool_id)'),
         );
     }
 }
```

this is my other model.

```
 class MiningPool extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function relations()
     {
         return array(
             'currencies' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'CryptoCurrency', 'mining_pool_currencies(mining_pool_id,currency_id)'),
         );
     }
 }
```

& this is my admin function from controller

```
 class MiningPoolController extends Controller
 {
     public function actionAdmin()
     {
         $model=new MiningPool('search');
         print_r($model->currencies);
         exit;
     }
 }
```

it gives empty array.Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Have you omitted your class' attributes (`mining_pool_id` and `currency_id`) for clarity or you forgot to add them to you class?

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that a `MiningPool` has many currencies but shouldn't the name for the relation on class `CryptoCurrency` be something like `"pools"`?

The names itself shouldn't matter , but maybe Yii is getting confused because both relations have the same name? Try changing the relation's name in class `CryptoCurrency` to something like `"pools"` instead and see what happens.

Comment: I changed the relation's name,but still it returns empty array.